# Lazyload only works on browser resize

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to lazyload all images on a page. The problem is that the images only actually show on a browser resize. If I don't resize the browser, the 'placeholder' only shows (the grey box which indicates that it still loading). I'm using [this](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload) jQuery lazyload plugin.

When I make a 'test' page with only jQuery and the Lazyload plugin it works. However when I actually use it on my own page (which has other plugins aswell, all working) I have this problem.

What could be causing this problem? Is there any way I could make this work? 
I would include the code I use if the page it isn't working on wasn't so big.